# Marking MySQL data as 'read'

Tags: php, mysql

I am working on a notification system on my website for users. I have a table for "events" that a user is notified of when they happen (friend requests, new followers, comments, etc.). Is there a way to insert a value like say 0 for unread and 1 for read in the //read column of the events table, for a particular event (upon request of the information by the user)? So that it is no longer notification worthy?

Comment: `UPDATE events SET read=1 WHERE id=XXX` doesn't work for you?

Comment: you will need to add a new table with user_id notification_id

Comment: a little sample of your work will be appreciated!

Comment: @FractalizeR I suppose that would work when/where would that query be executed?

Comment: @user1174762 I guess this query should be executed exactly when user has read specified event.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yep. Just store your column as `TINYINT(1)`. The MySQL literal `TRUE` evaluates to 1 and `FALSE` evaluates to 0, as expected.

(This is assuming your events table stores the individual events that get assigned to users, not the general event types that can occur.)

#### Usage

```
SELECT * FROM events WHERE user_id = [user_id] AND read = 0    #list all for user
UPDATE events SET read = 1 WHERE event_id = [event_id]         #mark as read
```

Answer (score 0):

Create an `isRead` of type `tinyInt` and set it accordingly to 0 and 1 for the particular event (i.e, the row read). 
If you map every event, comment, posts, etc to every user then you need to have a separate table `keysTracker` containing foreign keys `event_id`, `comment_id`, `post_id` and then a `user_id` that can map the user's read/unread status by linking them in query statements.

```
$query="SELECT * FROM event JOIN keysTracker ON event.event_id=keysTracker.event_id WHERE user_id='6' AND isRead='1' ";
```

In that way if you have common set of events, for instance "elections 2011" you are making sure that you are not adding duplicate event entries but only new `user_id` for that `event_id` in another table.

This whole process is called normalization and suggest you read [more here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization)